# I want to display error when user entered value that is not between 00:00 and 23:59, but im getting error

Tags: vb.net

I want to display error when user entered value that is not between 00:00 and 23:59, but im getting error, below is my code

```
Dim tm As String = If(mskTime.MaskCompleted, mskTime.Text, "")
If tm = "" Then
   err.AppendLine("- Time cannot be empty")
   ctr = If(ctr, mskTime)
ElseIf TimeSpan.Parse(tm) < TimeSpan.Parse(0) Or TimeSpan.Parse(tm) > TimeSpan.Parse(24) Then
   err.AppendLine("- Time should between 00:00 and 24:00")
   ctr = If(ctr, mskTime)
End If
```

If i entered 99:99, error message below is appeared

> System.OverflowException: 'The TimeSpan could not be parsed because at least one of the numeric components is out of range or contains too many digits.'

and i cant code as `TimeSpan.Parse(0:00)` and `TimeSpan.Parse(23:59)`

I have also tried

```
Dim minTime As String = "00:00"
Dim maxTime As String = "23:59"
TimeSpan.Parse(tm) < TimeSpan.Parse(minTime) And 
TimeSpan.Parse(tm) > TimeSpan.Parse(maxTime)
```

and it is also getting same error

Comment: And what error do you get?

Comment: Maybe you should use error handling?

Comment: Why not use a `DateTimePicker` instead, which will handle validation and parsing automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`99:99` does not come under timespan and thus it can't be parsed hence, the error.

Check if it can be parsed before parsing - Using `TryParse`

Here you go -

```
Dim tm As TimeSpan
If TimeSpan.TryParse(tbname.Text, tm) Then
    If tm < TimeSpan.Parse(0) Or tm > TimeSpan.Parse(24) Then
        MsgBox("Should be between 0 to 24")
    Else
        MsgBox(tm.ToString()) 'or your code
    End If
Else
    MsgBox("Entered Wrong value for time")
End If
```

If you still have the problem, please let me know.